# Deploy java apps to azure container apps

Tags: java, azure, docker, azure-aks, azure-container-apps

We have containerized our java application . The application has successfully been deployed on our on-prem environment on a vm. But rather than following a lift and shift approach , we plan to use azure container apps . I tried deploying the app through portal but was not successful. The image is obtained from acr . The following command just needs to be run to deploy the container from the image :

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 -e var-name="xyz" -v mount_folder:/mnt/xyz <image-name>
```

I was having problem setting up the environment vars and the mounts and also was confused as to where to write the docker run command in order to deploy the app through azure container services .

Can please someone help ....Thanking in anticipation!

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a Docker Run command directly. Using the **Portal**, when you create a new Container App, you set environment variables in the **App Settings** tab. Enable Ingress with **Accepting Traffic from anywhere** and set the **Target port** to 8080.

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts?pivots=aca-cli#temporary-storage) on how to create a mount to temp storage.